# proactive message sending in MS Teams Bot not working

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a Bot and added to Skype and Microsoft Teams. Both are responding fine for user messages (reply to user messages).

Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages), I tried to send (ad-hock) proactive messages to users. This worked with Skype but it not with Microsoft Teams. It also did not provide any error messages.

Do I have to adjust any settings in Microsoft Teams or Office 365 in order to send proactive messages? Or is there any other specific way to send proactive messages for Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what was the error. Following code line should be added before calling SendToConversationAsync, CreateConversationAsync etc..

**MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(ServiceUrl);**

And I tested this for [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages) and [sample source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot-CSharp/blob/master/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs). Both are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this is found in this article: [Starting a 1:1 conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/bots1on1#starting-a-11-conversation). There's also some [sample source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot-CSharp/blob/master/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs) although it's part of a larger project.

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried [sample source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot-CSharp/blob/master/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs), values I used in all parameters are correct, but it throws below (401 Unauthorized) exception when try to execute CreateConversationAsync method. 

(System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Authorization for Microsoft App ID <my app id> failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized'').

Please help!